# How to control popup's width for leaflet-feature's popup in R?

Tags: r, popup, leaflet

I would like to control the width of a leaflet-feature popup via R, how can I do that?

```
  output$HomeMap <- renderLeaflet(leaflet() %>% 
                              addTiles() %>% 
                              setView(1.93, 41.48, zoom = 3) %>% 
                              addPolygons(data = subset(world, name %in%  datasourceInput()), 
                                          color = datasourceColor(), 
                                          weight = 1, 
                                          popup = datasourcePopups()
                              ))
```

I do not understand how to control the options associated to the popup..

Many thanks in advance for your help on this issue and best regards!

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I am trying to figure out how to increase the width of the pop-up box for a leaflet map in R, but I haven't had any luck yet...

Answer (score 9):

I had a similar issue in creating the series of maps that I am working on right now.  Any formatting that I would want to be done on the html/css/javascripted page, is made inside quotations, I used double quotes example: `"<br>"` to create a line break and start the next piece of information on the next line.

To give order to it, I used a set of tables...I had 16 rows with text and wanted to use the last row for a png image. It worked, but the image made the text scale off the side of the popup above...the background did not scale with it.

So I did some playing around with the code, scoured the net, and then inserted this line of code at the very top of my popup variable:

```
myPopUp<- paste("<style> div.leaflet-popup-content {width:auto !important;}</style>", 
myvariable, "some copy to print", another variable)
```

Making sure the entire popup is inside of the `paste` function and now the popup automatically adjusts to the size of the content. *This does mean that you need to pay attention to your copy length and appropriately size any images in your popups.*

I have mine set up to pull 16 values and a graph from one of 292 census tracts and drop in the right data and cached images, then re-scale and it is working flawlessly. You might want to give it a try.

this is the magic code:  `"<style> div.leaflet-popup-content {width:auto !important;}</style>"`

This is how it looks[image: the popup sized relative to the content]

Now if only I could make the popup anchor somewhere that I approved of consistently!

Comment: Great solution.  You could also use `opacity` to add some transparency so context is not entirely lost underneath the popup.  See https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/opacity/.  Happy to demo if you would like.

Comment: This fixed the issue for me!

Answer (score 8):

@bethanyP's answer will work in all cases.  I thought some additional detail might be helpful.  I commented inline to explain each step.

```
library(leaflet)

# example from https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/popups.html
content <- paste(sep = "<br/>",
                 "<b><a href='http://www.samurainoodle.com'>Samurai Noodle</a></b>",
                 "606 5th Ave. S",
                 "Seattle, WA 98138"
)

leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>%
  addPopups(-122.327298, 47.597131, content,
            options = popupOptions(closeButton = FALSE)
  )

# according to ?popupOptions can specify min/maxWidth
#  set min and max width the to force a width
leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>%
  addPopups(
    -122.327298, 47.597131,
    content,
    options = popupOptions(
      closeButton = FALSE,
      minWidth = 300,
      maxWidth = 300
    )
  )
    
# on the other hand, it appears that we only have maxHeight
#  so height cannot be controlled in the same way
leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>%
  addPopups(
    -122.327298, 47.597131,
    content,
    options = popupOptions(
      closeButton = FALSE,
      maxHeight = 20
    )
  )

# let's extend the example to show how we can use
#   htmltools to add CSS to control our popups

# could also use the approach suggested in
#  the other answer, but I think this is more
#  fitting with typical HTML/JS convention

lf <- leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>%
  addPopups(
    -122.327298, 47.597131,
    content,
    options = popupOptions(
      closeButton = FALSE,
      # not necessary but adding a className
      #   can help in terms of specificity
      #   especially if you have multiple popups
      #   with different styling
      className = "myspecial-popup"
    )
  )

library(htmltools)
browsable(
  tagList(
    tags$head(
      #  more specific is better
      tags$style(
        'div.myspecial-popup div.leaflet-popup-content-wrapper {
          height: 400px;
          opacity: .5;
        }'
      )
    ),
    lf
  )
)
```